# Access UserControl by name (String)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

Can we access a `UserControl` by its name? For example, I've already made a `UserControl` (in the same project) with the name `uc1`, and a `Panel` named `Panel1`, so something like:

```
Dim a As String = "uc1"
Panel1.Controls.Add(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this instead:

```
Dim c As Control = Me.Controls("uc1")
```

or

```
Dim c As Control = Me.Controls.Find("uc1", True)(0)

If c IsNot Nothing Then
    Panel1.Controls.Add(c)
End If
```

But why not just add:

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(uc1)
```

(assuming your control is stored as `uc1` internally -> `Dim uc1 As Control ...`.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Not anything close that what's in your snippet, you can't add strings to the Controls collection.  But you can index the Controls collection with a string to get a control reference.  Like this:

```
Dim ctl as New MyUserControl
ctl.Name = "foo"
Panel1.Controls.Add(ctl)

...

Dim ctl as MyUserControl
ctl = DirectCast(Panel1.Controls("foo"), MyUserControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this old question since I was looking for the same answer.
The previous answers all assume that you already know the name of the usercontrol. If you want to load the usercontrol by a given string variable then you can use the following code.

```
Dim ControlName as string = "Namespace.ControlName"
Dim oType As System.Type = Type.GetType(ControlName)
Dim obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
Panel1.Controls.Add(obj)
```

This will add the usercontrol `ControlName` to the `Panel1` control. If your usercontrol is within the same project then the namespace to use is your own root namespace. You can find this namespace in the project properties.